Spring Boot and React app CORS errors (Hosted on Azure)
Hi to all that can help me.
I've been sitting here for days on end and I can't figure out how to get my Spring Boot and React app working.
The frontend is deployed as an Azure Static Web App and the spring boot backend as an Azure Web App.
Initially, everything worked fine when I tested locally but once I deployed to Azure the login does not work anymore. The basic functionality of the app is a portal where you have a product page that you can add to orders. Adding a product to an order and viewing/editing an order requires both authentication. This part of the app works fine, I click on the add to product button and it takes me to the google auth page where I select an account to sign in with. After redirection, I can't view orders and I keep on getting asked to log in...
However, when I run an endpoint (deployed backend) in my browser to get the currently logged in user, it shows the user I just selected on the deployed frontend. The same request in the frontend gives the following:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' (redirected from '') from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
I've tried about everything and even disabled CSRF at some point on the backend. The flow on the local development was what I was looking for:
Adding a product or viewing/editing orders requires authentication. Going to these pages or clicking the buttons took me to Google Auth and I signed in. Afterwards I could add products to orders and edit orders. I don't know what to do anymore :(
package com.xavier.client_backend.config;

import com.xavier.client_backend.domain.entities.ClientEntity;
import com.xavier.client_backend.repositories.ClientRepository;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.OAuth2User;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final ClientRepository clientRepository;

    public SecurityConfig(ClientRepository clientRepository) {
        this.clientRepository = clientRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors(cors -> {
                CorsConfigurationSource source = request -> {
                    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
                    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("<redacted_url>"));
                    configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
                    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
                    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
                    return configuration;
                };
                cors.configurationSource(source);
            })
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                auth.requestMatchers("/api/products/**").permitAll();
                auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
            })
            .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2.successHandler(successHandler()))
            .logout(logout -> logout
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler())
            );
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        return (request, response, authentication) -> {
            OAuth2User oAuth2User = (OAuth2User) authentication.getPrincipal();
            String email = oAuth2User.getAttribute("email");

            ClientEntity client = clientRepository.findByEmail(email);
            if (client == null) {
                client = new ClientEntity();
                client.setName(oAuth2User.getAttribute("name"));
                client.setEmail(email);
                clientRepository.save(client);
            }

            SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
            handler.setDefaultTargetUrl("<redacted_url>");
            handler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        };
    }
}


Edit 2:
Here is an ProductList.js file I have for reference to these calls:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const ProductList = ({ isAuthenticated }) => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [client, setClient] = useState(null);
    const [showToast, setShowToast] = useState(false);
    const [toastMessage, setToastMessage] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchClientAndProducts = async () => {
            try {
                const clientResponse = await axios.get(
                    `https://backendurl.azurewebsites.net/api/clients/me/`,
                    { withCredentials: true }
                );
                if (clientResponse.status === 200) {
                    setClient(clientResponse.data);
                    const productsResponse = await axios.get(
                        `https://backendurl.azurewebsites.net/api/products`
                    );
                    const productsData = await productsResponse.data;
                    setProducts(productsData);
                } else {
                    setClient(null);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching client or products:", error);
                setClient(null);
            }
        };
        fetchClientAndProducts();
    }, []);

    const handleAddToOrder = async (productId, productName) => {
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
            window.location.href =
                "https://backendurl.azurewebsites.net/oauth2/authorization/google";

            return;
        }

        try {
            // Check if there is an existing order for the client
            const ordersResponse = await axios.get(
                `https://backendurl.azurewebsites.net/api/orders/client/${client.id}`,
                { withCredentials: true }
            );
            const orders = ordersResponse.data;

            if (orders.length > 0) {
                // There is an existing order, update it
                const existingOrder = orders[0]; // Assuming only one open order at a time
                const updatedOrderItems = [...existingOrder.orderItems];
                const existingItem = updatedOrderItems.find(
                    (item) => item.productId === productId
                );

                if (existingItem) {
                    existingItem.quantity += 1;
                } else {
                    updatedOrderItems.push({ productId, quantity: 1 });
                }

                const updatedOrder = {
                    ...existingOrder,
                    orderItems: updatedOrderItems,
                };

                await axios.put(
                    `https://backendurl.azurewebsites.net/api/orders/${existingOrder.id}`,
                    updatedOrder,
                    { withCredentials: true }
                );
                setToastMessage(`${productName} added to existing order`);
                setShowToast(true);
                setTimeout(() => setShowToast(false), 3000); // Hide toast after 3 seconds
            } else {
                // No existing order, create a new one
                const newOrder = {
                    clientId: client.id,
                    orderDate: new Date().toISOString(),
                    orderItems: [{ productId, quantity: 1 }],
                };

                const response = await axios.post(
                    `https://backendurl.azurewebsites.net/me/api/orders`,
                    newOrder,
                    {
                        withCredentials: true,
                    }
                );
                if (response.status === 201) {
                    setToastMessage(`${productName} added to new order`);
                    setShowToast(true);
                    setTimeout(() => setShowToast(false), 3000); // Hide toast after 3 seconds
                } else {
                    console.error("Failed to add product to new order");
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error adding product to order:", error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="container mt-4">
            <div className="row">
                {products.map((product) => (
                    <div className="col-md-3 mb-4" key={product.id}>
                        <div className="card h-100 text-center">
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <h5 className="card-title">{product.name}</h5>
                                <p className="card-text">Price: R{product.price.toFixed(2)}</p>
                                <button
                                    className="btn btn-primary"
                                    onClick={() => handleAddToOrder(product.id, product.name)}
                                >
                                    Add to Order
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            <div
                className="toast-container position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3"
                style={{ zIndex: 9999 }}
            >
                <div
                    className={`toast ${showToast ? "show" : "hide"}`}
                    role="alert"
                    aria-live="assertive"
                    aria-atomic="true"
                >
                    <div className="toast-header">
                        <strong className="me-auto">Notification</strong>
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            className="btn-close"
                            onClick={() => setShowToast(false)}
                        ></button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="toast-body">{toastMessage}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ProductList;

Here are the errors present in the browser:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backendurl.azurewebsites.net/api/clients/me/' from origin 'https://mango.5.azurestaticapps.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

mango.5.azurestaticapps.net/:1 Access to fetch at 'https://backendurl.azurewebsites.net/api/clients/me/' from origin 'https://mango.5.azurestaticapps.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

The backend and frontend url has been changed a bit. Thank you for any help!

CSRF is a different security issue and has nothing to do with CORS. Check out this answer of mine on how to handle correctly setup CORS on backend, as well try searching for some other resources, e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors

Thank you for the reply! I actually saw your post a day ago and added your first solution to mine. I've made an edit to my post and added my current security config, is there anything you can spot that seems to be wrong here?

No, it looks correct, but just keep in mind allowed origin has to be the exact domain, as in correctly http or https as well as exact domain name and exact port (e.g. http:// foo.com). If it still doesn’t work you will have to provide more info as in on which exact domain your us code is running (feel free to change few letters), and what request was made

@JAsgarov I have updated the post again, thank you for any help. I really can't seem to figure this out at all. Please see one of the files I have attached for a reference to the calls in the frontend.

@XavierReynolds Enable cors in your azure backend app.

@XavierReynolds Goto your backed azure web app search for Cors-> enable Allow cors and paste the your frontend URL.

@XavierReynolds Enable cors like this in your Azure Backend Web App.

I have allowed CORS in the Azure web app since the start, but unfortunately that didn't help either @AsleshaKantamsetti

@XavierReynolds If possible, Share your github repo?

@AsleshaKantamsetti https://github.com/Xavier893/case-study here is the git repo

Did you used @CrossOrigin annotation in the controller. Check once if it is working?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
